# Can an eigenvalue be any algebraic number?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, irrational-numbers

Given a matrix $M$ with integer coordinates in general we know that each eigenvalue is an algebraic number.

Is it true that for every algebraic number $\alpha$ exists a matrix $M$ with integer entries such that $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $M$?

In case of yes a proof would be very nice.

In case of no, it would be nice to know what we do know about the possible eigenvalues.

thanks Till

Comment: It has to be an algebraic integer, i.e. a root of a polynomial of leading coefficient 1. And your question will be yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the condition that $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer. Note that if $M$ has integer entries, then the characteristic polynomial of $M$ is a monic polynomia with integer coefficients, and hence the only eigenvalues are algebraic integers.

Now let $\alpha$ be an arbitrary algebraic integer satisfying some $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0$. Then the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) satisfies what you want:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&\dots&0&-a_{0}\\1&0&\dots&0&-a_1\\0&1&\dots&0&-a_2\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&\dots&1&-a_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}$$